# php-cs-fixer does not work on visual studio

Tags: php, visual-studio, php-cs-fixer

I am trying to use "php-cs-fixer" plugin with visual studio code.

I read this topic : [topic](https://medium.com/@armorasha/php-cs-fixer-how-to-install-vs-code-2020-windows-10-75b6d5ed03ce)

I followed all the steps. When I try to format the code, I see a brief message in the bottom tool bar "php-cs-fixer finished". But the code is not formatted at all.

Here is my settings , perhaps you will see something ? Precision : I am on widows environment.

```
    {
  "editor.fontSize": 12,
  "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
  "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
  "editor.wordWrapColumn": 120,
  "files.autoSave": "onWindowChange",
  "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,
  "[php]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "junstyle.php-cs-fixer"
  },
  "php-cs-fixer.lastDownload": 1632503694554,
  "php-cs-fixer.exclude": [],
  "php-cs-fixer.onsave": true,
  "php-cs-fixer.rules": "@PSR2",
  "php-cs-fixer.allowRisky": false, //it is safe not to allow risky linting
  "php-cs-fixer.pathMode": "override",
  "php-cs-fixer.autoFixByBracket": true,
  "php-cs-fixer.autoFixBySemicolon": false,
  "php-cs-fixer.formatHtml": true,
  "php-cs-fixer.documentFormattingProvider": true,
  "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 10,
  "blade.format.enable": true,
  "[blade]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "onecentlin.laravel-blade"
  },
  "editor.rulers": [80],
  "php-cs-fixer.executablePath": "C:\\Users\\Domi\\AppData\\Roaming\\Composer\\vendor\\bin\\php-cs-fixer.bat",
  "php.suggest.basic": false,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Solarized Light",
  "php-cs-fixer.config": "C:\\Users\\Domi\\AppData\\Roaming\\Composer\\vendor\\bin\\config.php_cs",
  "[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here : https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/5696

The config.php_cs was not correct. Here mine which works fine :

```
    <?php

return (new PhpCsFixer\Config())
    ->setRules([
        '@PSR2' => true,
        'array_indentation' => true,
        'array_syntax' => ['syntax' => 'short'],
        'combine_consecutive_unsets' => true,
        'class_attributes_separation' => ['elements' => ['method' => 'one',]],
        'multiline_whitespace_before_semicolons' => false,
        'single_quote' => true,

        'binary_operator_spaces' => [
            'operators' => [
                // '=>' => 'align',
                // '=' => 'align'
            ]
        ],
        // 'blank_line_after_opening_tag' => true,
        // 'blank_line_before_statement' => true,
        'braces' => [
            'allow_single_line_closure' => true,
        ],
        // 'cast_spaces' => true,
        // 'class_definition' => array('singleLine' => true),
        'concat_space' => ['spacing' => 'one'],
        'declare_equal_normalize' => true,
        'function_typehint_space' => true,
        'single_line_comment_style' => ['comment_types' => ['hash']],
        'include' => true,
        'lowercase_cast' => true,
        // 'native_function_casing' => true,
        // 'new_with_braces' => true,
        // 'no_blank_lines_after_class_opening' => true,
        // 'no_blank_lines_after_phpdoc' => true,
        'no_blank_lines_before_namespace' => true,
        // 'no_empty_comment' => true,
        // 'no_empty_phpdoc' => true,
        // 'no_empty_statement' => true,
        'no_extra_blank_lines' => [
            'tokens' => [
                'curly_brace_block',
                'extra',
                // 'parenthesis_brace_block',
                // 'square_brace_block',
                'throw',
                'use',
            ]
        ],
        // 'no_leading_import_slash' => true,
        // 'no_leading_namespace_whitespace' => true,
        // 'no_mixed_echo_print' => array('use' => 'echo'),
        'no_multiline_whitespace_around_double_arrow' => true,
        // 'no_short_bool_cast' => true,
        // 'no_singleline_whitespace_before_semicolons' => true,
        'no_spaces_around_offset' => true,
        // 'no_trailing_comma_in_list_call' => true,
        // 'no_trailing_comma_in_singleline_array' => true,
        // 'no_unneeded_control_parentheses' => true,
        // 'no_unused_imports' => true,
        'no_whitespace_before_comma_in_array' => true,
        'no_whitespace_in_blank_line' => true,
        // 'normalize_index_brace' => true,
        'object_operator_without_whitespace' => true,
        // 'php_unit_fqcn_annotation' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_align' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_annotation_without_dot' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_indent' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_inline_tag' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_no_access' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_no_alias_tag' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_no_empty_return' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_no_package' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_no_useless_inheritdoc' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_return_self_reference' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_scalar' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_separation' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_single_line_var_spacing' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_summary' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_to_comment' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_trim' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_types' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_var_without_name' => true,
        // 'increment_style' => true,
        // 'return_type_declaration' => true,
        // 'self_accessor' => true,
        // 'short_scalar_cast' => true,
        // 'single_blank_line_before_namespace' => true,
        // 'single_class_element_per_statement' => true,
        // 'space_after_semicolon' => true,
        // 'standardize_not_equals' => true,
        'ternary_operator_spaces' => true,
        // 'trailing_comma_in_multiline_array' => true,
        'trim_array_spaces' => true,
        'unary_operator_spaces' => true,
        'whitespace_after_comma_in_array' => true,
        'space_after_semicolon' => true,
        // 'single_blank_line_at_eof' => false
    ])
    // ->setIndent("\t")
    ->setLineEnding("\n")
```

;